# How to publish a mod on Steam for a game without Steam Workshop?

Tags: modding, steam, steamworks

I'd like to publish a mod for a game that doesn't have Workshop or any community modding options.

I could go to Steamworks and publish it as a standalone game... but I don't see any option to "require" the user to have access to the base game to install it -- which is a requirement for the mod to work.(So it will appear on Steam with its own "store" page but doesn't allow to be downloaded unless the account holder also owns the base game)

I've spent days Googling this, but the only documentation I can find is how to add mods to Steam using Source, which I am not using. The mod is free if that matters at all.

Would like to use Steam because it's much easier to push updates to the mod than using NexusMods or ModDB. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible on Steam to offer DLC for a game of someone else. You could perhaps publish it a stand-alone game, but then you will get plenty of complaints for people who try to play it without having the base game installed.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks, I kind of figured as much. Appreciate the clarification!